# Are questions about reasoning behind results off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, off-topic

Just going over some of the unanswered questions today and came across these questions:

[Are people who win the lottery more likely to go bankrupt?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/are-people-who-win-the-lottery-more-likely-to-go-bankrupt)

[Interpreting people's motivation from body language](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5562/interpreting-peoples-motivation-from-body-language)

[Do bumper stickers cause increased driver aggression?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5438/do-bumper-stickers-cause-increased-driver-aggression)

All of them are tagged with psychology and all of them appear to be asking about the science behind a particular claim and not asking about a specific claim itself. Two of them even link to studies answering the claim itself, but that is not what the real question behind the question is.

I want to ask if these types of question are on topic here? To me they would be better asked on a psychology site rather than on this site. I have flagged the first one and voted to close, but then I noticed there were more and all of them have some upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

I think the latter two deserve to be closed as "Not a Real Question" and I have done so. They have no answers and are .. not really concrete questions, as you pointed out.

The first one is, I think, a real question that can be answered with science, and there are a number of studies on this topic.